# Resize circle in google maps v3 (MVC Objects)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i took the sample code from here ---> https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/articles/mvcfun/step6

and i have added some code in order to have a maximum and a minimum resize range..
I have succeeded to make the circle stop in these two ranges but the resize marker does not stop such as the circle...

the only thing i have changed was from this

```
RadiusWidget.prototype.setDistance = function() {
  // As the sizer is being dragged, its position changes.  Because the
  // RadiusWidget's sizer_position is bound to the sizer's position, it will
  // change as well.
  var pos = this.get('sizer_position');
  var center = this.get('center');
  var distance = this.distanceBetweenPoints_(center, pos);

  // Set the distance property for any objects that are bound to it
  this.set('distance', distance);
};
```

to this

```
RadiusWidget.prototype.setDistance = function() {
        // As the sizer is being dragged, its position changes.  Because the
        // RadiusWidget's sizer_position is bound to the sizer's position, it will
        // change as well.
        var min=0.5;
        var max=15;
        var pos = this.get('sizer_position');
        var center = this.get('center');
        var distance = this.distanceBetweenPoints_(center, pos);
        if (distance < min){ distance = min;}
         if (distance > max){distance = max;}





        // Set the distance property for any objects that are bound to it
        this.set('distance', distance);
      };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I put the limits on the distance in the 'drag' event listener it works better for me:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(sizer, 'drag', function() {
      // As the sizer is being dragged, its position changes.  Because the
      // RadiusWidget's sizer_position is bound to the sizer's position, it will
      // change as well.
      var min=0.5;
      var max=15;
      var pos = me.get('sizer_position');
      var center = me.get('center');
      var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(center, pos)/1000;
      if (distance < min) {
        me.set('sizer_position', google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center,min*1000,google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(center,pos))); 
      } else if (distance > max){
        me.set('sizer_position', google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center,max*1000,google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(center,pos)));
      } 
      // Set the circle distance (radius)
      me.setDistance();
    });
  };
```

Note: I used the [spherical geometry computeDistanceBetween method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) to compute the distance), requires including that library.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_mvcfun_step6_limitCircle.html)

Comment: ooh thank you so much! that worked perfect for me! keep the good work! thanks again!